# libgdx app doesn't run on android device, works fine on desktop

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I'm learning to work with libgdx and I tried to run a very simple app
on my android device but it doesn't open. The screen of my phone turns horizontally and then immediately turns back. It runs fine when I run it on desktop. My phone is a oneplus 3t. The only thing I did was show an image on screen. I haven't touched the android launcher and usb debugging is enabled on my phone. I know there a other questions like this but I haven't found a solution there. This is what android studio tells me:

```
04/06 19:37:42: Launching AndroidLauncher
$ adb install-multiple -r -p com.mygdx.game 
D:\JavaGameDev\Game3\android\build\intermediates\split-
apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.mygdx.game/com.mygdx.game.AndroidLauncher" -a 
android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 9593 on device oneplus-
oneplus_a3003-ba73d782
Application terminated.
```

Comment: hopefully you not modified `AndoridManifest` file that generated by LibGDX. once try to kill adb server and start again. may be it helped.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I'm sorry but what is the adb server? No I haven't modified that file.

Comment: adb is included in the Android SDK Platform-Tools package. Find in **android_sdk/platform-tools/**, run command `adb kill-server` there then run `adb start-server`

Comment: @AbhishekAryan No it still doesn't work, thanks for trying to help though

Comment: This is not logcat..please share the logcat or any error trace if any are there,
And please post your manifest, and the code snippet that you are trying to implement.